# Errors in connecting an Arduino to Ros Groovy

Tags: ros, arduino, rosserial, rosserial-python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to get an Arduino Uno hooked up to Ros Groovy; I've been following the Hello World tutorial for rosserial_arduino. When running

> rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyACM0

I'm able to connect for a second, and I start getting the error:

> [ERROR] [Walltime: ...] Lost sync with device, restarting...

I noticed my Arduino code is still running even though it lost connection (I have a flashing LED indicator). Its not publishing anything to "Chatter" however - not even once before it disconnects.

Please let me know how I might be able to fix this!

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66955/errors-in-connecting-an-arduino-to-ros-groovy/) by [asriraman93](https://answers.ros.org/users/5035/asriraman93/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2013-07-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there, I've come to a similar situation in ROS Indigo. This was mostly due to having the Arduino IDE open with the Serial Port open.
After I uploaded the code to the arduino and closed the IDE and restarted the rosserial server the error was gone.

---

Originally posted by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) with karma: 700 on 2017-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2